# Is having a while loop inside a for loop considered a nested while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, nested

Can having a while loop inside a for loop be considered a nested while loop?
How can I do this same problem using do while?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMS 3

int main() {
    // insert code here...
    int highVal;
    int lowVal;
    int i;
    printf("---=== IPC Temperature Analyzer ===---\n");

    for (i=1;i<=NUMS;i++){
        printf("Enter the high value for day %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&highVal);
        printf("Enter the low value for day %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&lowVal);

        while((highVal < lowVal)||(highVal >= 41 || lowVal <= -41)){

            printf("Incorrect values,temperature must be in the range -40 to 40,high must be greater than low\n");
            i--;
            highVal=1;
            lowVal=0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the results I need to be getting but the assignment calls for using a nested while loop (or do while) as well as for loop to prompt the user.

Comment: "nested while loop" is not a technical or precise term, so you will need to ask your teacher/professor what does and doesn't count.

Comment: your "nested while loop" is not a nested while loop, it is a badly written `if`. You're supposed to have the `scanf`s *inside* the inner loop.

Comment: It's definitely a nested loop. Now is it nested while loop? Well, while or for loops are not really a thing. They are just different ways to make loops. You can use a while loop and for loops interchangeably

Answer (score -1):

> Can having a while loop inside a for loop be considered a nested while loop?

No, it'd just be a nested loop, the same as this would be a nested loop:

```
foo:
    z = baz();
    x++;
bar:
    y++;
    if(x < 100) goto bar;
    if(y < 100) goto foo;
```

Note that you can convert a `for()` into a `while` by separating out the pieces. For example, this:

```
    for (i=initial; i<=MAX; i++) {
        do_something();
    }
```

..is equivalent to this:

```
    i=initial;
    while (i<=MAX) {
        do_something();
        i++;
    }
```

In a similar way you can convert `while()` into `if` and `goto` fairly easily (and therefore can convert `for()` into `if` and `goto` too). For example, the previous `for()` and `while()` examples are equivalent to this:

```
    i=initial;
start:
    if( !(i<=MAX) ) goto end;
    do_something();
    i++;
    goto start;
end:
```

Comment: Technically correct, but I won't tell to use `goto` to a student, rather to anyone!

Comment: @Swanand: I'm not suggesting `goto` should be used (but I do think it's good to understand how a compiler might reduce `for()` into `while()`, and `while()` into `goto`, and then convert the `goto` into assembly language with conditional branches). Of course replacing `for()` with an equivalent `while()` (so that OP's code ends up with a "while inside another while", or a "nested while" that the assignment requested) is the main part of the answer.